# How to create a tiered hierarchy from a flat file in javascript?

Tags: javascript, arrays, loops, hierarchy

I'm trying to create a hierarchical data-set based on my current flat data-set. So what I would need would be this:

- [0 … 99]

  - 0:Object

    - Genre: "Comedy - Musical"
    - Studio: "Paramount"
    - Title" "Titanic"
  - 1:Object

    - Genre: "Comedy - Musical"
    - Studio: "Buena Vista"
    - Title" "Monsters, Inc."
  - 2:Object

So forth and so on

I'd like to have this:

- 0:Object

  - Genre: "Comedy - Musical"

    - Studio: "Paramount"

      - Title: "Titanic"
      - Title: "Another Title"
    - Studio: "Buena Vista"

      - Title: "Monsters, Inc."

I can't figure out a method to accomplish this. I've only gotten the 2 tier hierarchy but I need the third level. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

I have this method.

```
function formatObjectToTreeStructure(data, filterName) {

            var filterList = [], allFilterList = [], constructedObject = [];

            data.children = data.data;

            for (var key in data.children[0]) {
                allFilterList.push(key);
            }

            for (var index = 0; index < data.children.length; index++) {
                var temp = null;
                var filterIndex = filterList.indexOf(data.children[index][filterName]);
                if (filterIndex == -1) {
                    filterList.push(data.children[index][filterName]);
                    temp = {};
                    temp[filterName] = data.children[index][filterName];
                    temp.children = [];

                    var tempChildren = {};
                    tempChildren[data.dataTableAlign.group1] = data.children[index][data.dataTableAlign.group1];
                    tempChildren[data.dataTableAlign.group2] = data.children[index][data.dataTableAlign.group2];
                    tempChildren[data.dataTableAlign.group3] = data.children[index][data.dataTableAlign.group3];

                    temp.children.push(tempChildren);

                    constructedObject.push(temp);

                } else {
                    var tempChildren = {};
                    tempChildren[data.dataTableAlign.group1] = data.children[index][data.dataTableAlign.group1];
                    tempChildren[data.dataTableAlign.group2] = data.children[index][data.dataTableAlign.group2];
                    tempChildren[data.dataTableAlign.group3] = data.children[index][data.dataTableAlign.group3];

                    constructedObject[filterIndex].children.push(tempChildren);
                }
            }
            return constructedObject;

        }
```

But this is as far as I've gotten. It only goes two levels though. I get Genre and it's children but I can't seem to figure out how to get all titles of the same Studio though.

Comment: What have you tried so far? StackOverflow is not a 'Code this for me'-site.

Comment: I edited the question

Answer (score 0):

May be you can do like this;

```js
function corrugate(data){
  return data.reduce((t,o) => {
                                t[o.genre]  ? t[o.genre][o.studio] ? t[o.genre][o.studio].push(o.title)
                                                                   : t[o.genre][o.studio] = [o.title]
                                            : t[o.genre] = {[o.studio]: [o.title]};
                                return t;
                              },{});
}

var list =[{genre:"Comedy", studio: "Std_A", title: "Movie_01"},
           {genre:"Comedy", studio: "Std_B", title: "Movie_02"},
           {genre:"Western", studio: "Std_A", title: "Movie_03"},
           {genre:"Thriller", studio: "Std_A", title: "Movie_04"},
           {genre:"Action", studio: "Std_C", title: "Movie_05"},
           {genre:"Thriller", studio: "Std_C", title: "Movie_06"},
           {genre:"Western", studio: "Std_B", title: "Movie_09"},
           {genre:"Thriller", studio: "Std_B", title: "Movie_10"},
           {genre:"Action", studio: "Std_A", title: "Movie_11"},
           {genre:"Western", studio: "Std_D", title: "Movie_12"},
           {genre:"Comedy", studio: "Std_D", title: "Movie_13"},
           {genre:"Action", studio: "Std_C", title: "Movie_14"},
           {genre:"Western", studio: "Std_D", title: "Movie_15"},
           {genre:"Thriller", studio: "Std_A", title: "Movie_16"}];

console.log(JSON.stringify(corrugate(list),null,4));
```